# libagl alphaPlaneWorkaround error messages in LogCat

Tags: android, logcat

I have recently noticed, while debugging an app, that LogCat reports numerous error ("E") messages with pid=92, tag=libagl and Message="uses alphaPlaneWorkaround".

The messages appear when my app's screen is redrawn, for example when it is scrolled.

I am using Android 2.1. I realized that these messages started appearing after I had turned on Animations in the phone's Sound & Display settings, and testing indicates that they appear if either the "All animations" or the "Some animations" option is selected and that they do not appear if I choose "No animations."

What causes these messages? Do they indicate a bug in my app or are they caused by the operating system?

Comment: I should have mentioned that the pid (92) is not the pid of my app. Some other process seems to be generating these error messages.

Comment: Did you get a chance to find out the exact cause? I am getting similar kind of logs.

Comment: kotmanish, no I never did find out. I turned off animations and I have not seen them again. Sorry not to be able to help.

Comment: The same thing worked for me too.Thanks for the reply.

Comment: I'm inclined to think that it's an interior API work around. Prolly just a note from the developer that did the work around. If you not noticing a performance decrease I would just ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

The message is more of a debug message than an error.  Chances are that the developer simply used the wrong log level, or it is their practice to flag software workarounds to highlight hardware/driver issues.

I noticed that a recent firmware update on Samsung devices introduced a lot of new logcat messages including battery charge errors that weren't previously there.  In fact the latest firmware appears to have introduced more errors than it solves so I am now considering rolling my own firmware (if I get time).

Unless you are spcifically calling other processes and it's not tagged with your application's PID then probably safe to ignore it.